# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/kernel/hungtask/vm_heart (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, file-io

I have created an android application with two activies i.e MainActivity and DBConfig Activity.
I have text inputs and a button to save and read data on different files in DBconfig. Here is the sample code:

```
private void saveFileData(String file_name, String text){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write(text.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String readDataCredentials(String file_name) {
        String text = "";
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(file_name);
            int size = fis.available();
            byte [] buffer = new byte[size];
            fis.read(buffer);
            text = new String(buffer);
            fis.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return text;
    }
```

I am not able to use readDataCredentials to read file data created from DBconfig in main Activity:

```
public void setConfigurations(){
        dBconfig = new DBconfig();
        //db credentials
//        String hostIP = "", username = "", port = "", password = "", database="";

        hostIP = dBconfig.readDataCredentials("host.txt").trim();
        username = dBconfig.readDataCredentials("username.txt").trim();
        password = dBconfig.readDataCredentials("password.txt").trim();
        port = dBconfig.readDataCredentials("port.txt").trim();
        database = dBconfig.readDataCredentials("database.txt").trim();

 }
```

I get the error below:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/kernel/hungtask/vm_heart (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
        at com.android.server.Watchdog.writeHungtask(Watchdog.java:904)
        at com.android.server.Watchdog.run(Watchdog.java:563)
```

I need help reading the data from the files in mainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Two points, readDataCredentials(String file_name) code inside should be in a loop because available() is about "stream blocking done by write or read controllers" (alike NIO blocking server) because of the stream "buffer size" NOT "file size" and to stop the loop you would need to know the file size regardless or you would need to put in an "if condition" to jump reading if it finds sometime it has zero to read, that code does not detect if it is "all completely read" or "partially read" , only how much data the process is prepared to send. However, the .txt files should be in the directory the "OS system is running in" just alike with a prompt or terminal to be in the same directory, if not, then that may at least be your FileNotFoundException occurring, so it would be wise to determine their actual location as there would be no guarantee where the system process is running in the file system.
And read(byteArray,0,fileLength) in my opinion would be simpler unless you genuinely needed to start stop manage a stream yourself.